# Creating / manage content - how is everybody doing it?

Tags: craft3

I need some ideas for creating content.
It's a bit of a pain the way i have it now.

I tested this: https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-content-builder-in-craft-cms
But i don't really like it because text and images are all over the place in the backend.
If i could combine certain stuff in blocks that i could move around it would be better.
But it seems like this (like in my example image) is not possible (images is a Super Table):
[image]
For example here: https://skulltronics.net/phantasialand-hoerspiel-und-videokassetten

I have the audio tape and video tape.
If i want to add the next tape and want it on top or between then i have to move every text and image block if i can't group them.

Then i have the links to the single view of the images. This are not the same images that you see on the pages. They are hi res and a mix of png and jpg.
At the moment a put them in by hand like:

```
<a title="FHD Ansicht" href="%%home%%media/phantasialand/guides/03/phantasialand-parkfuehrer-11-1972-1973-back-4K.png" target="_blank">FHD Ansicht</a>
```

At the moment I'm using %%image1%% in my content and they are replaced by the code in the template.

Problem is if i want to add more i always need to count the rows.
[image]
row 1 = %%image1%%, row 2 = %%image2%%...

For example this: https://skulltronics.net/phantasialand-autoaufkleber-und-sticker
Looks like this when creating the entry:

```
<h2 class="mb-3">Phantasialand Aufkleber 1978</h2>
<a href="%%home%%media/phantasialand/sticker/phantasialand-aufkleber-1978-bob-bahn-cine-2000-alt-berlin-western-train-jet-neptunbrunnen-4K.png" target="_blank">%%image1%%</a>
<p class="mt-1 mb-1">Original Größe: 11.8 cm &Oslash;</p>
%%share1%%

<h2 class="mt-4 mb-1 mb-700-n3">Phantasialand Aufkleber 198?</h2>
<a href="%%home%%media/phantasialand/sticker/phantasialand-aufkleber-198x-gelb-chinatown-pagode-jet-4K.png" target="_blank">%%image2%%</a>
<p class="mb-1">Original Größe: 20.3 cm Lang</p>
%%share2%%

<h2 class="mt-4 mb-1 mb-700-n3">Phantasialand Aufkleber 198?</h2>
<a href="%%home%%media/phantasialand/sticker/phantasialand-aufkleber-198x-gruen-chinatown-pagode-jet-4K.png" target="_blank">%%image3%%</a>
<p class="mb-1">Original Größe: 20.7 cm Lang</p> 
%%share3%%
```

If i now need another sticker in between i can use %%image15%% because that attachment is row 15 after adding it or i need to change them all when editing if i want it in right order.

Also with the nystudio107 way: If you create a image link then you make a text block with
`<a href="link.html" target="_blank">`
Then comes the attachment and then another text block with just
`</a>` ?

So how do others handle/create/manage there content/entries?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by “…i don't really like it because text and images are all over the place in the backend”. Almost every project we build uses a content builder built with matrix blocks in this way. It's easy to dev for, and intuitive for clients. I think you may have misunderstood the methods described in that article.

Comment: I'm completely confused by the percentage symbol, what are you using these for?

Comment: @user3788089 This is how i do it: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30946/how-to-place-assets-in-plain-text-fields . Somebody else is also doing it that way: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12847/replace-placeholder-string-in-text-field-with-html-generated-by-asset-query

Comment: So what you’re essentially doing is adding images and referencing them from a text field? Could you not just use redactor and upload images within that? Is the skulltronics page you linked to an example of how you want the page to look?

Comment: What is the context of this page, are all the items events?

Comment: @user3788089 its my private page. Its about a German amusement park, my collection like the guides from all the years: https://skulltronics.net/phantasialand-parkfuehrer-parkplaene-und-broschueren . I don't like WYSIWYG. The code is never clean. The problem is every page is different and images come in all kind of formats.

Comment: I agree about wysiwyg. I think there is a better way to do this, will post a solution shortly...

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified example, but this is how I'd approach user-manageable page content, using a content builder. Each content type gets its own block in a matrix field:

[image]

Which allows authors to add whichever page content blocks they require, in whatever order they like:

[image]

Simply add whatever blocks your design requires.

Comment: By all over the place i mean you have a text block with just a heading. Then a assets block with a image. Then another text block with a paragraph. Then a assets block again. And so on... . Then you want to put something new in between or want to move what belongs together (heading, paragraphs, some images) somewhere else on the page. That means you need to move all the single blocks. And like i wrote if you want to make image links you have a text block with some html, then asset block, another text block with html (a tag)...

Comment: a) you can add a new block anywhere, without moving all the blocks, by clicking the cog on the right of a new block and choosing the block type to insert above it. b) To create linked images you can just add a 'link' field to your image block and, if it is populated, use it to wrap you image. No need for more than one block to do that.

Comment: Personally, I would never allow a cms user to create html; that's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: for me WYSIWYG is a disaster. It's my own side and i'm so only person who creates content.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this another way. If it were me I would create a new section called ‘guides’ with each guide having its own entry. That way you can have as many fields as you want without the content page getting overwhelming.

I would then use the same content building technique as nystudio but include a new block called Guides, you can then create an entries relation field that links to your guides section.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you guide data is now reusable on any page.

Comment: every guide already is its own structure entry?

Comment: Ah ok, well what I’m getting at is to create a field setup specifically for you content. Ie it looks like each item has some images, some text, and two links so male a block for that.

Comment: i wish there where a Craft forum. Showing/explaining things here is a pain because you can't add code/images in comments. Then this formatting here...

Comment: Agree with this, not a fan of stack exchange.